# Python xlwings-VBA issue

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlwings

I'm new to python-excel automation. I have made a script that work properly when run from python, but when I am trying to run it from excel, I get some errors.

The script is something like:

```
sheet1=pd.read_excel("xxx.xlsx",sheet_name="A", header=1,usecols=["d","e","f","m","n"]))
sheet1.dropna(subset=["f"], inplace=True)
sheet1=sheet1[~sheet1["f"].astype(str).str.startswith("A")]
column_name=list(sheet1["f"].unique())
    
def fct1():
   for index in range(len(column_name)):
        for element in sheet1.index:
            *do some things and append the results in a dictionary*

   ws = xw.Book('xxx.xlsx').sheets['B']
   for i in range(len(column_name)):
        *write the results*
```

In VBA I just added:

```
Sub test()
    RunPython "import RoomData; RoomData.fct1()"
End Sub
```

Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround (not sure if it is the best option)- I created the dataframe by another method, and after I discarded the columns that were not important + the rest is the same:

```
sheet = xw.Book('xxx.xlsm').sheets['A'].range((3, 4), (1000, 12)).value
sheet1 = pd.DataFrame(sheet, columns=xw.Book('xxx.xlsm').sheets['A'].range((2,4), (2, 12)).value)
sheet1.pop('D')
sheet1.pop('E')
sheet1.pop('H')
sheet1.pop('G')
sheet1.dropna(subset=["f"], inplace=True)  # delete lines where no info on "Tableau"
sheet1 = sheet1[~sheet1["f"].astype(str).str.startswith("A")]
column_name = list(sheet1["f"].unique())

def fct1():...
def fct2():...
def fct3():...
```

Still, if somebody have any idea to do this in some other way, please don't hesitate :)